# How to prove that certain probabilities are exponentially small?

Tags: probability, inequality

I am trying to solve some problems where one's required to show that the probability that a certain event happens is exponentially small on some positive integer variable.

For example, it seems that for all $n \geq 3$,
$$\frac{(2n-5)! \cdot (2n-5)^{n-2}}{(3n-7)!} \leq \left(\frac{8}{9}\right)^n,$$
but I could not prove it. I've tried Stirling's approximation for dealing with the factorials but the resulting expression is a total mess. Also, calculating certain limit only helps for sufficiently large values of $n$.

Is there a standard way of proving this kind of thing?

Comment: Have you tried induction?  Can you show that $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_N}<\frac89$?  I haven't done it, but it's the first thing I would try.

Comment: One way to go might be to use $\sqrt{2 \pi} \sqrt{n} n^n e^{-n} \leq n! \leq e \sqrt{n} n^n e^{-n}$ which hold for all $n \geq 1$ and give you an approximation of the factorial within a constant factor. Using that gives a bound of $\frac{e \sqrt{2n-5}}{\sqrt{2\pi} \sqrt{3n-7}} \left ( \frac{2n-5}{3n-7} \right )^{3n-7} e^{n-2}$ (if I didn't make any mistakes) which seems to get you most of the way there.

Comment: To be a bit more specific, the first factor is like a constant that is at least eventually less than 1, the second factor is like $(8/27)^n$ and the third factor is like $e^n$, and $e<3$. The annoying part for purposes of getting an inequality that holds for $n \geq N$ for some explicit $N$ is juggling all the correction terms.

Comment: You can get the same kind of $\frac{8e}{27}<\frac{8}{9}$ type of structure out of the sequence of ratios as well.

Comment: @saulspatz Yes, it reduces to proving that $\frac{(2n-3)^n}{(2n-5)^{n-2}} \leq 12x^2 - 36x + 180/3$, but then I don't know what to do with those exponents.

Comment: Do you mean $n$ on the right-hand side?

Comment: @saulspatz Yes, it's $n$ instead of $x$.

Comment: @Ian Yes, that's Stirling's approximation I mentioned. I tried to upper bound the expression as much as I could but small changes made the inequality fail.

Comment: Divide both sides by $(2n-3)^2$ so that the left-hand side becomes $\left(1+\frac2{2n-5}\right)^{n-2}$  That looks like it will increase to $e$, but I haven't checked.

Comment: I'd be good to go if it weren't for the $-7$ in the exponent of that second factor. With that there you have some hassle, where you have to use some of the slack you got from the other two factors to sort it out.

Comment: @saulspatz As for the r.h. expression, $\frac{12n^2 - 36n + 60}{4n^2-12n+9} \geq \frac{12n^2 - 36n + 60}{4n^2-12n+20} = 3$. The l.h. seems to be bounded below by $e$ and above by $3$ (just by picture, this would be remaining step of the proof), the limit is $e$.

Comment: @Ian I am struggling in getting the slack you mentioned from those factors. The exponents don't really help.

Comment: 1. $\frac{e \sqrt{2n-5}}{\sqrt{2\pi} \sqrt{3n-7}}$ is less than 1. 2. $\left ( \frac{2n-5}{3n-7} \right )^{3n}$ is less than $(8/27)^n$ at least once $n \geq 3$. 3. $e^{n-2}<3^n$. So the product of those three is less than $(8/9)^n$ for $n \geq 3$.  But the extra $\left ( \frac{2n-5}{3n-7} \right )^{-7}$ needs to be mitigated by the slack from the other pieces.

Comment: @Ian Got it. I'll continue with this in mind.